# multiplying big numbers using recursion and array

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am supposed to write and algorithm which uses recursion (Divide-And-Conquer) to multiply two arrays.These arrays hold big  Numbers that are greater than long(int 64) or double capacity.
Would please help to write this algorithm in C#?

Comment: Sure. You go first. What have you got so far?

Comment: i have some method which does it without using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start: divide each number into 2 pieces, multiply the pieces recursively, and add them up with the right offset.

Comment: i know this, but how to implement by arrays ?! i save my big numbers in two arrays.

Comment: @Keith, do you mean use normal array multiplication procedure but for actual multiplication use divide and conquer?

Comment: Divide the arrays in half.  Use the following formula for 2k-bit multiplication: (A + B * 2^k) * (C + D * 2^k) = A*C + (A*D + B*C) * 2^k + B*D 2^(2k).  Divide your first multiplicand in half to get A and B, the second multiplicand to get C and D.